# Can a OBJ_REF_DELTA object in a git packfile have a base object later in the packfile?

Tags: git, http

I'm writing a parser for git packfiles (and specifically, git packfiles returned from the smart HTTP API).

When parsing an OBJ_OFS_DELTA object in the packfile, it seems fairly clear from the [packfile spec](https://git-scm.com/docs/pack-format) that the base object it refers to to cannot be later in the packfile than the delta object itself, since the offset is used as a negative offset.

However, if an OBJ_REF_DELTA object's base object is in the same packfile, can that be later in the file?

The reason why this is important is that I'm writing a parser that, as much as possible, is "streaming" to use as little memory or local disk as possible.

Comment: I suggest to ask this question on the Git mailing list (git@vger.kernel.org).